# How to Loop through pscutomobject array and add an extra property?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have the following pscutomobject array script

```
$pscoArray = @()

foreach($server in $Servers) {
    $pscoArray += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $server
    }
}                   

$iteration = 0
```

how do i loop through the resulting $pscoArray and add to it a new member called 'iteration' and increment that based on number of objects that already exist in the array?

i.e.

```
$pscoArray = $pscoArray | %{ Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'iteration' -Value $iteration; 'iteration' = $iteration++}
```

ultimate output should look like this, assuming there are 3 servers in this example

```
iteration Server
------    ------
1         server1
2         server2
3         server3
```

so iteration has to be added as a member at position 0, at the beginning of the pscustomobject, although i dont know how would i do that either

p.s. i know i can just add iteration directly in the forloop, but i need this for a different purpose.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The code looks like you could do with a simple string array as the PsCustomObjects only have one property? If you want to add new properties to the objects while iterating the array, have a look at [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member)

Comment: @Theo ya so im trying to add a new member, called iteration. but it should also count however many objects already exist in the pscoarray and increment the new iteration member that was added. this has to be done OUTSIDE the foreach loop because as i said, i have some other purposes for this so i can just add the mmber inside the foreachloop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the code that generates your array

```
$Servers = 'svr1', 'svr2', 'svr3'
$pscoArray = foreach($server in $Servers) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $server
    }
}
```

Then the simplest way of doing this may be by using a for(..) loop

```
# add a new property called "iteration" to each member of the array
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pscoArray.Count; $i++) {
    $pscoArray[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'iteration' -Value ($i + 1)
}

$pscoArray
```

Output:

> ```
> Server iteration
> ------ ---------
> svr1           1
> svr2           2
> svr3           3
> ```

---

**Update**

If you want to get the iteration property listed first, you could do:

```
# add a new property called "iteration" as first property to each member of the array
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pscoArray.Count; $i++) {
    $pscoArray[$i] = $pscoArray[$i] | Select-Object @{Name = 'iteration'; Expression = {$i + 1}}, *
}

$pscoArray
```

Output:

> ```
> iteration Server
> --------- ------
>         1 svr1  
>         2 svr2  
>         3 svr3
> ```

Comment: question: can the iteration be rearraneged to be at the beginning of the pscoArray? so this code is perfect, i just need iteration to be the first column :)

Comment: @Cataster I have added a new code suggestion so each object in the array will be overwritten by a new object that has the iteration property in first, combined with everything the object already had in it (that is the asteriks `*` at the end of the Select-Object)

Comment: @Cataster Glad to have helped!

Comment: question, lets say i want to output the same pscoArray twice but the 2nd output only contain for example any rows that DONT have srv2. now i know how to exclude members, i.e. `$pscoArray2 = $pscoArray | Select * -Exclude iteration` but how can i exclude rows with particular values? i.e. `$pscoArray2 = $pscoArray | Select * -Exclude ALL rows/objects where value = srv2` i say all because lets assume there are multiple iterations where srv2 is repeated

Comment: @Cataster In that case do `$pscoArray | Where-Object { $_.Server -ne 'svr2' }`

Comment: oh thats simple enough!

Comment: @Cataster If you just want duplicate servers to be removed from the array, do `$pscoArray = $pscoArray | Select-Object Server -Unique` _BEFORE_ you enter the loop. Using that every server wil be listed only once if that is what you need.

Comment: no its more about a different purpose. its much more complicated here lol, but i might need that in the future, thanks!

Comment: Hey man, do you know why I could possibly have gotten a downvote like 20 days later on this thread? I dont understand why people do that, it's like they search for old threads and just downvote them for no reason watsoever. Smh

Comment: @Cataster No, I don't know why some people do that. The question to me is perfectly legit and I see no reason for downvoting whatsoever. I evened the score with a +1. Cheers!